# i keep running into a "cannot find symbol error" at line 32

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Source {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Enter the two numbers in the input console
    int number1 = scan.nextInt();
    int number2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(lcm(number1, number2));
  }

  public static int lcm(int number1, int number2) {
    int LCM = 0;
    if (number1 > number2) {
      LCM = number1;
    } else {
      LCM = number2;
    }
    for (int LCP = LCM; LCP <= 100000000; LCP++) {
      if ((LCP % number1 == 0) && (LCP % number2 == 0)) {
        int temp = LCP;
      }

    }
    return temp;
  }

}
```

I think I properly defined the return variable. I know that its a petty issue yet I cant pinpoint the error or the adjustment that I have to make.

Comment: You have defined temp inside if scope and returning it outside.  declare temp outside the loop.

Comment: The variable `int temp` is defined inside the `if()` block, so it only "exists" inside the `if()` block. This means, it does not exists in the `return temp;` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the variable `temp` inside your `for loop` inside your `if condition`. It does not exist outside of that scope, which means that once that if condition ended, the variable no longer exists. So when you try to use it with `return temp` the program does not know what you are referring to.

To fix it, you just need to define temp in the scope of your entire function similarly to how you defined `int LCM = 0;` and then assign the value in the if condition.

working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Source {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Enter the two numbers in the input console
    int number1 = scan.nextInt();
    int number2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(lcm(number1, number2));
  }

  public static int lcm(int number1, int number2) {
    int LCM = 0;
    int temp;
    if (number1 > number2) {
      LCM = number1;
    } else {
      LCM = number2;
    }
    for (int LCP = LCM; LCP <= 100000000; LCP++) {
      if ((LCP % number1 == 0) && (LCP % number2 == 0)) {
        temp = LCP;
      }

    }
    return temp;
  }

}
```

You can read more about scopes [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Define `temp` outside your loop function, and also you might want to break execution once you have found the value you were looking for:

```
public static int lcm(int number1, int number2) {
    int LCM = 0;
    int temp = 0; 
    if (number1 > number2) {
      LCM = number1;
    } else {
      LCM = number2;
    }
    for (int LCP = LCM; LCP <= 100000000; LCP++) {
      if ((LCP % number1 == 0) && (LCP % number2 == 0)) {
        temp = LCP;
        break; // Finish loop 
      }

    }
    return temp;
  }
```

Comment: I assumed lcm stands for Least Common Multiply, not gcm

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the ‘temp’ variable inside the if statement. So, it has become a local variable. Local variables cannot be accessed outside the condition or function in which they are defined. So, you need to define the ‘temp’ variable outside the if statement. Modified code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Source {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Enter the two numbers in the input console
    int number1 = scan.nextInt();
    int number2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(lcm(number1, number2));
  }

  public static int lcm(int number1, int number2) {
    int LCM = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    if (number1 > number2) {
      LCM = number1;
    } else {
      LCM = number2;
    }
    for (int LCP = LCM; LCP <= 100000000; LCP++) {
      if ((LCP % number1 == 0) && (LCP % number2 == 0)) {
          temp = LCP;
      }

    }
    return temp;
  }

}
```